# Regex remove additional spaces and line breaks but not all

Tags: regex

I am using regex to remove additional spaces. But I would like to keep single line-breaks.

```
'/\s+/'
```

How can I keep single line breaks?

Remove only extra unnecessary spaces and line-breaks.

I've tried `'/\s{2,}/'` but this still removes my line-breaks.

Comment: Can you provide test cases and the language you're working with?

Comment: Use `'/\h{2,}/'`. Or, `'/[^\S\n]{2,}/'`, or `'/[^\S\n\r]{2,}/'`

Answer (score 1):

This will match extra spaces and new lines:

```
(?<= ) | +$|(?<=\n)\n
```

Explanation (space literals replaced with "[space]"):

```
(?<=[space])[space] | Match any space that has a preceding space
|                   | or
[space]+$           | Match one or more consecutive spaces at the end of a line
|                   | or
(?<=\n)\n           | Match any new line that has a preceding new line
```

The global and multi-line flags should be used with this expression. Simply replace the matches with nothing.

#### [Try it here](https://regex101.com/r/GhgpQF/2)